# Date is incorrectly sent to backend daterangepicker.js

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker, odoo-14

I have a date in this format: `02/15/2022 02:00:00` but when it goes to the Backend, the date plus 5 hours arrives: `2022-02-15 07:00:00`
The library I use is: daterangepicker.js

FRONT:

[image]

POSTGRES:

[image]

How can I solve it?

UPDATE: library for date(moment.js)

[image]

Comment: What timezone are you in? Could the date be being converted to UTC? (As it should be when being stored.

Comment: @phuzi update my question with more detail

Comment: So you've found why there is 5 hours difference. 07:00 will be UTC and 02:00 will be local time given the 5 hour difference between local and UTC.

Comment: @phuzi Yes, how can I solve it, any idea, thxs?

Comment: Are you sure it's wrong? What issues is it causing?